# ASP.Net Identity User foreign key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have added a custom collection to asp.net identity user as below

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
 {
      [MaxLength(100)]
      [Required]
      public string FirstName { get; set; }

      [MaxLength(100)]
      [Required]
      public string LastName { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<UserGroup> Groups { get; set; }
 }
```

When I access User.Groups property, identity framework is looking for UserGroups table, but my actual table mapped is cm_usergroup.
How do I make Identity framework to look for this table?

Comment: please explain more about your model configuration

Comment: Simply adding `[Table("cm_usergroup")]` attribute over `UserGroup` model should be enough. Have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/entity-framework/4161/code-first-dataannotations/15378/table-attribute#t=201609151018585280851).

Comment: @AdilMammadov is correct but please post your UserGroup class as well so we can check it.